# How to clear text field using Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, appium-ios

I am using the following:

- MAC OS X
- Appium 1.5.3
- Jar files: java-client-4.0.0.jar,
  java-client-4.0.0-sources.jar, selenium-java-2.53.1.jar +
  selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
- Android device: Galaxy S5,
  4.4.2 \ 5.0.0

I am having a problem clearing a field text on browser. I tried using:

- clear
- sendKeys("")
- sendKeys right + delete + backspace (each key i send, simply move the cursor to the beginning of the text field)

None seem to work.

< Editing >
My code:

```
    WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@content-desc , 'Email')]"));
    emailField.click();
    emailField.clear();
    emailField.sendKeys("abc123@gmail.com);
```

Comment: can you please add your code snippet.

Comment: Removed tags from title and reworded title (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)
. Improved lay-out a bit.

Comment: @AmiPatel added my code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Galaxy Note 4. In my case, I've used ADB Input Event and it works fine now.

```
driver.pressKeyCode(„67”); // Android delete KEY_EVENT, driver is Android Driver
String command = "adb shell input text abc123@gmail.com";
Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```